# Reuse interstital ads in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, admob

I'm adding ads to my SwiftUI application with Google AdMob and I have the following case. I have a button in some view, which when tapped will show an ad. However, I can also tap the button as many times as I want, and with each tap a new and different ad should appear.

This is the code for the Interstitial

```
final class Interstitial:NSObject, GADInterstitialDelegate{
    var interstitial: GADInterstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: TestKey)
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        LoadInterstitial()
    }
    
    func LoadInterstitial(){
        let req = GADRequest()
        self.interstitial.load(req)
        self.interstitial.delegate = self
    }
    
    func showAd(){
        if self.interstitial.isReady {
           let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
           self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: root!)
           self.LoadInterstitial()
        }
       else{
           print("Not Ready")
       }
    }
    
    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        self.interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: TestKey)
    }
}
```

And this is the View I use for testing

```
struct Add: View {
    @State var interstitial:Interstitial = Interstitial()
    
    var body : some View{
      Button(action: {
        self.interstitial.showAd()
        self.interstitial = Interstitial()
      }){
        Text("My Button")
      }
    }
}
```

Since I am in test mode I don't know for sure if when I move to the real ads, they will be unique and different from the previous one. I also tried it with a real ad unit and it kept showing the same ad over and over again.

Any help and guidance will be very appreciated!

Comment: Load ad, show ad, close ad, something else, load ad, show ad, close ad, ... is the ad life cycle I use in Java. Maybe check if ad is closed, before you load again --> look into manual again, to see if you have all - maybe you find code samples. What you find should also be working ... Anyway, please note that the Interstitial implementation has just changed very much with new latest ads library (you can also still use the old library). https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial-fullscreen